# React Native setState directly when onPress

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I spending few hours to think about how to `setState` to the `onPress` component to change the props I want.

**In real project, `SpecialItem` is render by `map` function, so I cannot create unique `state` for each child and put it on `isfavourite` props**

For example, I want the second `SpecialItem` `onPress` to change the `isfavourite` to `true`

```
render(
    return(
        <View>
            <SpecialItem ref={'sp_1'} isfavourite={false} onPress={()=> this.checkFav()}/>
            <SpecialItem ref={'sp_2'} isfavourite={false} onPress={()=> this.checkFav()}/>
            <SpecialItem ref={'sp_3'} isfavourite={false} onPress={()=> this.checkFav()}/>
        </View>
    );
);
```

As request, this is the `map` function exmaple:

```
renderSpecialItem = () =>{
    return speciallist.map((item, i)=>{
        return(
          <SpecialItem key={i} isfavourite={item.isFav} onPress={()=> this.checkFav()}/>
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: What if you have an obj with all your ref and a boolean value in your state ? {sp_1:false, sp_2:true, sp_3:false} and just set your isFavorite value to be egual to your obj state value ?

Comment: @Nevosis sorry, not really understand what your try to say ,do you have example ?

Comment: please add your map function

Comment: @LinasMickevicius added the map function

Comment: and please post this.checkFav

Comment: `checkFav` the function Im looking for, I not sure how to `setState` when `onPress`

Answer (score 0):

You can always save the index (from map loop) and then check if current index is equal to this one from state

```
isFavourite={this.state.selectedItemIndex === index}

onPress={()=> this.checkFav(index)}
```

Comment: `isfavourite` props when `map` already assign the `boolean` value, how can put the `this.state` together ?

Comment: oh, ok, so you will probably need to modify the source of the boolean value. It all depends what you want to achieve. Only client side change in that moment? If this is the case You can also check if there is selectedItemIndex set, and if not just use standard boolean value from map loop `isFavourite={this.state.selectedItemIndex ?
 this.state.selectedItemIndex === index : item.isFavourite}` or something like that

Comment: I try to use your example `isFavourite={this.state.selectedItemIndex ? this.state.selectedItemIndex === index : item.isFavourite}` , not what I'm looking for, it just switch between the child, I want it change the single way and not affect other child component.

Answer (score 0):

Use a state to re-render the list when something is modified.

```
class Special extends React.Component {
    state = {
        speciallist: [],
    }
    checkFav(i) {
        const {
            speciallist
        } = this.state;
        const newList = speciallist.slice()[i]['isFav'] = true;
        this.setState = {
            speciallist: newList
        }
    }
    renderSpecialItem = () => {
        const {
            speciallist
        } = this.state;

        return speciallist.map((item, i) => {
            return (
                <SpecialItem key={i} isfavourite={item.isFav} onPress={this.checkFav.bind(this, i)}/>
            );
        });
    }
}
```